# Como deixo esses botões do lado da caixa de texto, usando flexbox?

Tags: html, css, banco-de-dados, flexbox

**HTML:**

Produtos | Cadastro
    


   Home 
 
  
    
       Pesquisar

## Cadastrar Produto

**Produto** 
 
        
  
       **Marca** 
       
  
      **Valor** 
       
  
      **Estoque**

```
  <div class="t"><button type="submit" class="botoes">Inserir</button>
<center> <button type="submit" class="botoes">Salvar</button> </center></div>
```

Listar Produtos

**CSS:** body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.navbar{
background-color : #383838;
overflow : auto;
}

.navbar a {
float: left;
padding: 12px;
color: white;
font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
background-color: #9ab452;
}

.home {
background-color: #405230;
}

.botao_pesquisa{
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
height: 35px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

.navbar input {
padding: 6px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 10px;
font-size: 17px;
border: none;
float: right;
}

.corpo {
background-color:#a8bf8c;
}

.texto{
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
margin: 20px 0 40px 0;
background: #f1f1f1;
border: none;
margin-left: 200px;
border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.rotulo{
margin-left: 205px;
}

.t{
text-align: center;
}

.y{
text-align: center;
}

.botoes {
background-color: #405230;
font-size: 12pt;
color: white;
padding: 20px;
width: 10%;
margin: 8px;
border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
margin-left: 100px;
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi, vc quer deixar os dois botões ao lado de um input.
Basta inserir nessa div class t o input e ficará alinhado:

```
<div class="t">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit" class="botoes">Inserir</button>
  <button type="submit" class="botoes">Salvar</button>
</div>
```